# How could i access to contacts db and change it in android?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I want to access to this path on android.

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

but i could not.i think because it s private.but i want to backup it and will restore it.

my phone in root.but i could not do that too.

what should i do?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found a way.

first your phone should be root!

and second step is to change `contacts2.db` permissions.
for that use below codes :

```
        Process p;   
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chown root.root /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db");
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db");
```

and after that you can access to it!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the database was meant to be accessed directly. Have you looked at the [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)?